# Compilation errors in qt header files vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

I am trying to test my qt project with cppunit. The tests project uses MFC.
I am using Visual studio 2010.

I have included the qt libraries , dlls and made other changes in the project settings like adding preprocessor definitions to compile the cpp file which I want to test.        But when I compile this cpp file, I get a lot of syntax errors, located in qt header files..The compilation output is given below:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: my_tests, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/ZI' with '/Zi'
1>cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/GS' with '/GS-'
1>cl : Command line warning D9025: overriding '/Zc:wchar_t' with '/Zc:wchar_t-'
1>  CSetting.cpp
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qiodevice.h(247): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qiodevice.h(247): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qiodevice.h(247): error C2805: binary 'operator <<' has too few parameters
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qiodevice.h(247): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qdebug.h(160): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qdebug.h(160): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qdebug.h(160): error C2805: binary 'operator <<' has too few parameters
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qdebug.h(160): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qdebug.h(160): error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qdebug.h(160): error C2065: 'T' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qdebug.h(160): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qdebug.h(178): error C2065: 'T' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qdebug.h(180): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qdebug.h(180): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qdebug.h(190): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qdebug.h(190): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'
1>c:\qt\4.8.2\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/io/qdebug.h(190): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

Please help me with these errors..

Answer (score 3):

You must be using QT 4.8.x or older.
All version before QT 5.x are compiled with

```
/Zc:wchar_t-
```

(it means: DO NOT treat WChar_t as built in type) which is not compatible with MFC, BOOST or CUDA libraries.
You need to switch to QT 5.x in which the flag changed to

```
/Zc:wchar_t
```

(without "minus" on the end) - it is compiled this way (they considered this as a flaw).

Or compile older version with /Zc:wchar_t, by changing it in source file:

```
QTSRC\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010\qmake.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess, but you sometimes get these kind of errors if you are missing the final semicolon after a class definition, or a closing bracket at any point.

```
class XXX
{
};  // <- this one could be missing
```

in your CSettings.cpp, check which file you include directly before QIODevice or QDebug. This is usually the faulty class (could be CSettings.h)

Comment: I have checked all the headerfiles, including CSettings.h. All the semicolons and brackets are in place..

Comment: I am including StdAfx.h in all the cpp files before including the Qt header files...Is this causing the problem..?
In that case what can be the solution? Because I must include StdAfx.h before other header files, right?

Comment: Hm try removing the Qt includes and see if you get other errors (except for "unknown symbol" ones, of course)

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem unless there is an error in StdAfx.h or in any header file which is included by it. Note that you can configure your project so it automatically includes StdAfx.h for all files, at least in VS 2008 (It's called "force include" or something somewhere in the compiler properties)

Comment: From your code: "Command line warning D9025: overriding '/Zc:wchar_t' with '/Zc:wchar_t-'" - disable the override and check what happens and then read my answer